# Creating equal and hashcode for a class using a map

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I have a class as shown below and wanted to create several instance of it where each object should be unique based on the content of map.

For this equals and hashcode functions should be specified and I'm looking a way to implement using the map.

```
private class A {

    private Map<String, Object> map;

    public A () {
        this.map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void addElement (String s, Object v) {
        map.put(s, v);
    }

    @Override public boolean equals (Object o) {
        // should be on map
    }

    @Override public int hashCode () {
        // should be on map
    }
}
```

Comment: The easiest way to get equals and hashCode implementations here would be to get your IDE to generate them.

Comment: @AndyTurner, Did not exactly got what you meant?